# Плавное увеличение картинки при наведении, с текстом сверху и затемненным фоном

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, битрикс

Подскажите код с использованием css и div, для реализации задачи:
Необходимо создать 9 блоков (через div) фотографий, которые при наведении медленно увенчиваются и на фотографиях расположен текст.

Пример нужной реализации, как на этом сайте (фотографии врачей):
https://newmed61.tilda.ws/personal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif; /* Альтернативы Roboto */
}

.item {
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2; /* По середине */
}

.item__title,
.item__description,
.item__image {
  position: absolute;
}

.item__title {
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item__description {
  bottom: 0;
}

.item__title,
.item__description {
  white-space: pre-line; /* Чтобы новые строки писались на этой самой новой строке */
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3; /* На самый передний план */
}

.item__image {
  max-width: 100%; /* Ширина не более самой ширины элемента */
  max-height: 100%; /* Высота не более самой высоты элемента */
  z-index: 1; /* На задний план */
  transition: transform 0.8s; /* Плавная анимация для transform со скоростью 800 миллисекунд */
  left: 50%; /* Центрируем по x */
  top: 50%; /* Центрируем по y */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Назад на 50% от размера элемента, чтобы он был посередине */
}

.item:hover .item__image {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1); /* Указываем translate(-50%, -50%) два раза, чтобы изображение не сдвигалось с места. Также указываем что элемент увеличится на 10% */
}


/***************************/

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* По 3 колонны каждая по ширине 33.3% */
  height: 350px; /* Не забудьте указать высоту!!! */
}

.list-item {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item list-item">
    <div class="item__title">Привет мир!</div>
    <div class="item__description">
      Привет, мир,
      это птичка!
    </div>
    <img class="item__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Icon_Bird_512x512.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="item list-item">
    <div class="item__title">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="item__description">
      Hello World,
      this is Linux!
    </div>
    <img class="item__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Icon_Pinguin_1_512x512.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="item list-item">
    <div class="item__title">Jet</div>
    <div class="item__description">
      Fastest Jet on the planet,
      no comments.
    </div>
    <img class="item__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Icon_Jet_512x512.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="item list-item">
    <div class="item__title">Sun</div>
    <div class="item__description">
      Wakes you up in the morning,
      no need to thank me.
    </div>
    <img class="item__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Favicon-baianolandia-512x512-2019.jpg" />
  </div>

  <!-- И далее по аналогии -->
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.
А где в коде указывается своя ширина блоков? Высоту я укажу, например 750рх

Я поняла, что сделать написано 33,3%. а как этот процент исправить?

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* По 3 колонны каждая по ширине 33.3% */
  height: 350px; /* Не забудьте указать высоту!!! */
}

Comment: А можно в ваш пример, на одну из картинок, добавить эффект наведения, затемнения и текст, как показано на этом сайте (левый пример): https://stylecss.ru/effekt-pri-navedenii-na-kartinku-s-tekstom-css/

Я пробовала добавлять код из html и css с этого сайта, но у меня не получается расположить 3 блока в один ряд, и выставить им свою высоту и ширину, и расстояние между блоками

Comment: @BlogK `А где в коде указывается своя ширина блоков?` -- нигде, grid сам выставляет ширину. `а как этот процент исправить?` -- Вы можете указывать ширину блокам самостоятельно, для этого пишите `width` в `list__item`. Вы кстати не правильно указали высоту, ещё нужно указывать до комментария.

Comment: @BlogK `А можно в ваш пример, на одну из картинок, добавить эффект наведения, затемнения и текст, как показано на этом сайте (левый пример)` -- пример нельзя, тут как-никак должен быть ответ только на один вопрос, но подскажу как это сделать. Блок `.item::before` должен быть прозрачным по стандарту, также указываете `transition`, чтобы был плавный переход прозрачности, далее при `.item:hover` у `.item::before` делаете его снова видимым. Ну а вместо того, чтобы делать приближение, делаем соответственно одоление указывая `scale(0.9)`, По стандарту не забываем указать `scale(1.1)`. А далее сами)